# PasswordBox CapsLock

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am using "MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit". Is there any style or property that shows a message when I focus on a passwordbox and capslock is activated? Thx!

Comment: AFAIK no - you have to code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `KeyDown` event to capture the keys and write your logic.